# Reusing DataTemplate

Tags: wpf

I have the below Expander but would like to use the DataTemplate as a Window Resource as I'll be using it in a couple of places. The only thing I'm unsure of is the Label with Content "Errors/Warnings:". This will be different from in each use of the template. Is there anyway I could still reuse the same template but pass in the text to use in this label? I'm already binding to an int (in the case below `lblOverallInt`) so I'm not sure how to pass in another value.

```
<Expander Header="{Binding Path=lblOverallInt, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Height="24">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="0">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource isZeroConverter}}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Style.Resources>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                    <Label>Errors/Warnings:</Label>
                    <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway I could still reuse the same template but pass in the text to use in this label?

You could bind to another property that returns "Errors/Warnings:" or some other string:

```
<Expander Header="{Binding}">
    <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Height="24">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding lblOverallInt}" Value="0">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=lblOverallInt, Converter={StaticResource isZeroConverter}}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Style.Resources>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                    <Label Content="{Binding YourPropertyName, FallbackValue=Errors/Warnings:}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
</Expander>
```

The `FallbackValue` value will be shown as a default value if the binding to `YourPropertyName` fails, for example if the `DataContext` to which the template is applied (the class with the `lblOverallInt` property) is missing this property.